# Loop on a variable delimited with gamma using Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel-8

I have in my database values with this form :

```
["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]
```

I'm using laravel and I want to loop on this variable to get each element for example get the element : `email1@gmail.com`.

I tried the following code :

I have the following array :

```
$emails :
    array:2 [▼
      0 => "["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]"
      1 => "["email3@gmail.com","email4@gmail.com"]"
    ]
```

So I'm using the following code to get each element :

```
$var = array();
          foreach ($emails as $key => $value) {
            $var[] = $value;
          }
```

I get the following result :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]"
  1 => "["email3@gmail.com","email4@gmail.com"]"
]
```

If you have any idea , please help

**UPDATE**

I have the following array :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]"
  1 => "["hajar.boualamia33@gmail.com","guernine.khadija@gmail.com"]"
]
```

And I did the following method :

```
$emailss = collect($emails)->flatten()->all();
 dd($emailss);
```

I get the following result :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]"
  1 => "["hajar.boualamia33@gmail.com","guernine.khadija@gmail.com"]"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Ha, tricky one. It seems that you have a PHP expression (an array) stored. So in order to extract the arrays, we need to evaluate them first.

Try this instead:

```php
$elements = [
  "['email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com']",
  "['email3@gmail.com','email4@gmail.com']",
];

$emails = collect($elements)
  ->map(function ($element) {
    return (eval("return \$element = " . $element . ';'));
  })
  ->flatten()
  ->all();
```

---

Try this:

```php
$elements = [
  ['email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com'],
  ['email3@gmail.com','email4@gmail.com'],
];

$emails = collect($elements)->flatten()->all();
```

This will get you:

```
=> [
     "email1@gmail.com",
     "email2@gmail.com",
     "email3@gmail.com",
     "email4@gmail.com",
   ]
```

Check this method [on the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-flatten).